# Eclipse Data Tools Platform (DTP) - MySQL not available

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, eclipse-dtp

I want to configure MySQL using Data Source Explorer, like [here](http://theopentutorials.com/post/uncategorized/eclipse-dtp-configure-mysql-datasource-data-source-explorer/)

However, MySQL doesn't appear on my list in Eclipse

[myList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPOC5.jpg)

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add connector to MySql in eclipse or use newer version of eclipse.

Comment: you mean by right-clicking on the project -> Build Path -> Add External Archives ? I did it and the connection to db works perfectly. But I can't configure DTP.